# What are the general steps to turn a PDE into a dynamical system $\dot x(t)= Ax(t) + Bu(t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

It is said that every boundary value PDE such as the heat equation can be turned into dynamic system of the type $\dot x(t)= Ax(t) + Bu(t)$ with appropriate I.C.

Can someone elaborate as to how to proceed in doing this?

Comment: I don't know if this is really correct. For the heat equation one uses Fourier transformation to get an ODE.

Comment: If you are OK with $x(t)$ being an element of an infinite dimensional space, you can write the heat equation in this form with $A = \Delta$.  Otherwise I don't see how it can be done.

Comment: Check textbooks on control theory. The wiki page may also help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.se/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Infinite_Dimensional.html?id=G_x-F-l2V2UC&hl=sv) is good (Google preview is available)